# CSS Hover Color All The Way To Edge

Tags: css

Can someone help what I need to do to make the "Home" and "Blog" portions of the main nav extend all the way to the end with the hover color? i.e. When I hover over either the hover color kicks in but there is still a little bit of area with the dark brown to the left and right respectively of the Home and Blog sections in the nav.

www.utahshutters.com

Comment: thanks. fairly new here.

Comment: i tried up voting and don't have the reputation to do so. will start accepting though. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your css from this:

```
    #nav ul{
       width: 950px;
       padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    #nav li a{
      padding 13px 17px 12px 15px;}

    }
```

to this

```
    #nav ul{
       //width removed
       padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }

    #nav li a{
      padding 13px 17px 12px 16px;

    }
```

Comment: still leaves just a little to the right of blog? i tried increasing 17 to 18 and made an entire new row.

Comment: Ive updated my answer (removed the width attribute). This seems to fix  it. If this answer has solved your problem please mark it as the answer (the tick at the top left of my answer) so that other people with a similar problem will know that this is your solution

Comment: will have to come back later and play with it more. removing width as you're updated answer shows still leaves space in FF. would assume causes issues in IE/C as well as previously had it in FF/C but IE was way off.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the list items in your nav bar add up to the full width you'd need to give each of the Lis an individual width which added up to the total.

The 'a' tags could just be made to be display:block to expand to the width of each LI.

Your nav bar ( UL ) either needs to have a width of 960px or to have no width on it.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: not completely. i'm just a little off with extra in the blog portion but then the sub nav i'm testing in the education part has the same issue.